# jquery ui button error

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Why does this code (taken from the demo sample at jquery ui), doesn't work for me? It says .button() is not a function.

Update: Tried loading from google no luck. Here is teh error

$(".demo button:first").button is not a function

Line 27

http://pastie.org/1039784

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="screen.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8" />


    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");
    google.load("jqueryui", "1.7.2");
</script>


</head>
<body>
    <div id="container" class="container">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".demo button:first").button({
            icons: {
                primary: 'ui-icon-locked'
            },
            text: false
        }).next().button({
            icons: {
                primary: 'ui-icon-locked'
            }
        }).next().button({
            icons: {
                primary: 'ui-icon-gear',
                secondary: 'ui-icon-triangle-1-s'
            }
        }).next().button({
            icons: {
                primary: 'ui-icon-gear',
                secondary: 'ui-icon-triangle-1-s'
            },
            text: false
        });

        });
    </script>


<div class="demo">

    <button>Button with icon only</button>
    <button>Button with icon on the left</button>
    <button>Button with two icons</button>
    <button>Button with two icons and no text</button>

</div><!-- End demo -->

    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a id="icon_only"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>              

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like your route to jquery may be wrong, try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");
    google.load("jqueryui", "1.7.2");
</script>
```

that should load the jquery and jquery ui libs from google servers and this way it should work fine

Comment: Nevermind, you were right, the google load worked, once I got the 1.4.2 and 1.8.2. version. What was wrong with loading it locally?

Thanks!

Comment: dont know, just it wasnt right :P i think it was "js/jquery.js" right? then it should be that your js folder isnt in the same folder as the script. 
Im glad it worked ;) anyway is better to use those libs at google, that way the request from the clients are parallel and load faster.